# How to center inline-block element with margin

Tags: html, css, centering

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="block1"></div>
    <div id="block2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#wrap{
    margin-top: 3em;
    border: solid 1px black;
    text-align: center;
}

div#wrap *{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12.5em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    height: 8em;
}

div#wrap *:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 8em;
}

#block1{
    background: orange;
}

div#wrap #block2{
    background: magenta;
}
```

These 2 blocks are supposed to be centered in responsive design mode. When the screen is wide enough to have 2 blocks in a row, the code works. But when I narrow the screen down, the top block is shifted to the left because of the margin:

[image]

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3kyyh6o4/1/)

Is it possible to fix this without media queries?

## Edit

I tried flex-box:

```
div#wrap{
    margin-top: 3em;
    border: solid 1px black;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/3kyyh6o4/2/)

Comment: You would need to remove the `margin-right` property from the first nested element.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Yes. But I need the margin when the screen is wide enough to contain 2 elements in a row. Is media query checking screen width the only solution?

Comment: It's probably the safest option with the current *inline-block* configuration. You may have more options available to you if you are willing to explore `flex-box` solutions.

Comment: as @UncaughtTypeError said, the easiest solution is to remove margin with media query but only if the width of boxes is know and fxed

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I tried flex, but couldn't make it work. Edited the question to show what I tried.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Edit done.

Comment: @TemaniAfif "only if the width of boxes is know and fxed" - yes, this is my case. But I thought if there is another solution with flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a container with negative margin, you don't need to vary the margin for the endpoints of the rows at different breakpoints and you can just go with inline-block. I set font-size to zero in the container so I can calculate my widths using percents without worrying about white space.

```css
div#wrap {
  margin-top: 3em;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12.5em;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 8em;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.block-container {
  margin: -20px;
  font-size: 0;
}

#block1 {
  background: orange;
}

#block2 {
  background: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="block-container">
    <div class="block" id="block1"></div>
    <div class="block" id="block2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user4035 so you were ok to use margin in both sides then ? :) by the way i don't understand the need of negative margin here .. you can remove them and padding also and it will behave the same, no ? as the main issue was centering which is fixed by adding margin on both sides

Comment: @TemaniAfif The neg margin is a habit for me and I don't think it does anything great here, but it's hows many grid layouts like bootstrap achieve full width grids without having to manage the margins at the end of rows when they wrap. http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

Comment: @TemaniAfif I played with this solution. Yes, the trick is to divide the margin between elements using margin-left and margin-right. Negative margin is used to consume the space after shrinking the container. But it creates horizontal scrollbar, so I removed it. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3kyyh6o4/4/)

Comment: @user4035 but i think that this solution is an alternative to what you have and is not a real fix for you issue (i have nothing against it of course! ) ... but your issue was to center element by having margin in only one side right ? or you are ok to use margin in both ? as in this case there is a lot of many other was too ;) and i would say that we won't have any issue since everything is symetric

Comment: @TemaniAfif "your issue was to center element by having margin in only one side right?" - my task was to create 2 blocks with a space between them in responsive design mode. So they could shift in a centered column when the screen is narrow.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Space should exist between the elements. Initially I created it using margin-right of the first element. It could be done using margin-left for the 2-nd element. Here it is created by adding the margin-left and margin-right of both elements. The symmetry solves the problem.

Comment: @user4035 ok, so i will undelete my answer as it can provide you with another alternative too ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah, but I am not sure, whether the items are centered in your solution: I tried it before you removed. Going to sleep now, it's 3:33 here now. So I'll reply in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use flex and `justify-content:space-around` and remove margin:

```css
div#wrap {
  margin-top: 3em;
  border: solid 1px black;
  justify-content:space-around;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div#wrap * {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12.5em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  height: 8em;
}

#block1 {
  background: orange;
}

#block2 {
  background: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="block1"></div>
  <div id="block2"></div>
</div>
```